# Match "And" if the preceding sentence has an "and"

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically, I want to do this:

> Text and text text. Text text. And text. (Don't match this "And.")
> Text and text text. **And** text. (Match this "And.")

Right now, I have this regex: `.*\b(and)\b.*\. And`. But it matches both `And`'s in the example above: https://regexr.com/65k52

How to modify this regex so it only matches `And` if the previous sentence has `and`?

Comment: Does it mean you want to use `.` + whitespace as a sentence separator sequence?

Comment: I would use something like ... [`/(?<=and[^.]+\.\s*[^.]*)and/ig`](https://regex101.com/r/aGLvzz/1/) ... which matches exactly the second `and`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thanks, this regex is shorter than the one in the answer.

Comment: @alexchenco ... in addition it also matches just the succeeding 2nd `and`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `.` + whitespace as a sentence separator sequence you can use

```js
(?=\S)[^.]*(?:\.(?!\s)[^.]*)*?\band\b[^.]*(?:\.(?!\s)[^.]*)*\.\s+And\b
(?=\S)(?:[^.]|\.(?!\s))*?\band\b(?:[^.]|\.(?!\s))*\.\s+And\b
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/h1Rn1x/3) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/h1Rn1x/4). *Details*:

- `(?=\S)` - next char must be a non-whitespace
- `(?:[^.]|\.(?!\s))*?` - zero or more (but as few as possible) occurrences of any one char other than `.` or a `.` that is not immediately followed with whitespace
- `\band\b` - whole word `and`
- `(?:[^.]|\.(?!\s))*` - zero or more (but as many as possible) occurrences of any one char other than `.` or a `.` that is not immediately followed with whitespace
- `\.` - a dot
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `And\b` - a whole word `And`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect the regex to be this long. But it works. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: Added `?` and `!` to sentence delimiters [in this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h1Rn1x/5). The second regex is shorter, but slower. The first one is longer but faster. The `(?=\S)` part is not obligatory, you can remove it, and when matching, `trim()` the result.